# border size not matching for circle

Tags: sass, pug, border, geometry

I have 2 divs with same border;

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
}
```

I want them to be circles, so I added border-radius: 50%;
And after that I discovered that their borders don't match anymore

Why is that?

Comment: Сan you make fiddle?

Comment: I made demo in codepen http://codepen.io/_massimo/pen/bwdgLk

Comment: That's just anti-aliasing due to pixel rounding. They are the same size, it's just that one is black and you can see it - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/kkWgQX

Comment: I deliberately made it black to show that the cyan is wider

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to `match` the circles- noted this when I removed the `border` for the `last` element

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
body div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
body .first {
  border-color: cyan;
}
body .last {
  /*border-color: #000;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
```

I guess this has something to do with how CSS renders the pixels (because pixels are discrete units)

Comment: just noticed Paulie_D's comments: *anti-aliasing due to pixel rounding*-  that must be the reason :)

Comment: no I need these borders (it's for more complicated thing)

Comment: I want that border of the second div covers totally the border of the first one

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible in CSS

Comment: I want to have an effect like without anti-aliasing. Is it possible?? that second border covers first one totally

Comment: @MaximBehar I think one of the way you can make it work here is by slightly adjusting border-width, width and height for the `last` element and giving some margin to the `first` element...

Comment: well, that's how CSS works... you can't solve this one... 
you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
div#container{ 
padding-top:10px; 
padding-left: 10px;
background:#CF0; 
width:800px;
height:220px; 
} 

.box{ 
position:absolute;
width:200px; 
height:200px; 
font-size:150px;
border-radius:150px; 
border:6px dotted #0F9; 
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box"><div>
```

you can change  circle border using border size increase/decrease & many more